# How to pass data from Java to Javascipt?

Tags: javascript, java, microservices

I would like to create a website that visualises different algorithms. I would like to implement and compute the algorithms in Java but visualise and present in to the user on a website so using JS, HTML and CSS. To be clear I don't want to use Java for backend, I just want to implement the algorithms and compute them using Java. How would I go about doing that? Could this be done using micro-services?

I know that you can't run java in a browser. I just want to have some kind of service that computes the algorithms and passes the data about how to render it to a client side which renders it.

Comment: why don't use implement your algorithms by JS as well?

Comment: Most of the browsers today can run Java. The support for Java Applets (a GUI framework) has been deprecated. As far as I know, the support for running Java isn't.

Comment: @TranHo I want to practise Java and I prefer it to JS. The only reason i want it to be a  website so that I can demonstrate it to someone. For example I can't simply demonstrate a plain Java application but with a website I can just the send the link.

Comment: for a demo, you can post to Github and share them a link. They can see your implementation but not visualization :-)

Comment: @TranHo But that kinda of kills the whole point of visualisation?

Comment: This Question is too broad for Stack Overflow. Voting to close. For general guidance and strategy advice, seek a discussion site such as CodeRanch.com

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can, suppose you have a java component that handles the data processing and algorithm.  This component can just be a simple java application that accepts parameters and produce some output.  You then have a back-end micro service, a REST API for your front-end to consume.  The back-end can be done with various frameworks and languages.  The back-end would invoke/make request to this java component.  You typically do this if you need heavy processing as a separate component.  Imagine you need to do heavy machine learning or data analytic.  Your back-end would make request to these component that do the heavy computing. Also if the processing is long and complex then you will have to do request, and poll for results.  There are quite a few things to consider, but it depends on your needs.

Comment: Where would I start with this? Would this Java component run on a server?

Comment: You can make a simple java command line application that takes in command line arguments.  Your back-end service will run on the same server as this java application.  When a certain request is made to the back-end, it would issue command to execute the java application with appropriate arguments and response back with the result output.   In short make a java application that return a "hello world" when execute.  Create a back-end that execute the java application and capture the output when a request is made.  Send the capture output back as response to the front-end.

Comment: How can I run Java on a server? Suppose I have an api written in Node, how would I tell it to run the java on a server?

Comment: Something like this, https://medium.com/stackfame/how-to-run-shell-script-file-or-command-using-nodejs-b9f2455cb6b7 your server should have java runtime install and your node back-end can execute that java program.  Note that this only work for fairly quick request within a few seconds.  If you're doing complex calculation in the java program that's going to take longer, then you will need to make multiple requests.  To start the java app, additional requests to poll on results.

Comment: Would i convert my java application into a jar file and run it in node as explained in the  article?